# How can i create a VIEW from a table, splitting a string in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, split, sql-view

I have the following table called *info_trade*:

| instrument_name | list_of_trade |
| --- | --- |
| USD/EUR | "2021-08-10 10:00, 100, 0.8, 0.02, ...; 2021-08-10 12:00, -30, 0.85, 0.03, ..; ..." |
| USD/CAD | "2021-08-10 10:00, 400, 1.3, 0.01, ...; 2021-08-10 13:00, -10, 1.32, 0.01, ..; ..." |

I want to build a VIEW with rows that contain (instrument_name, date, other_field) for each trade into list_of_trade (each trade is divided by ';' delimiter and each field is divided by ',' delimiter).
Like this:

| instrument_name | date | position | price | tc | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USD/EUR | 2021-08-10 10:00 | 100 | 0.8 | 0.02 | ... |
| USD/EUR | 2021-08-10 12:00 | -30 | 0.85 | 0.03 | ... |
| USD/CAD | 2021-08-10 10:00 | 400 | 1.3 | 0.01 | ... |
| USD/CAD | 2021-08-10 13:00 | -10 | 1.32 | 0.01 | ... |

How can I do it writing in a Postgresql script?

Answer (score 1):

You need to first split the elements that are separated by `;` into rows. Due to the whitespace before/after the delimiter, it's easier to use `regexp_split_to_table` to do that.

The elements for each item can then be split using `regexp_split_to_array()` to get an array. The result columns are then the elements of the array:

```
select instrument_name, 
       trades[1] as date, 
       trades[2]::int as position,
       trades[3]::numeric as price, 
       trades[4]::numeric as tc,
       trades[5] as "...."
from (       
   select t.instrument_name, 
          regexp_split_to_array(x.trade, ',\s+') as trades
   from info_trade t
     cross join regexp_split_to_table(trim(';' from t.list_of_trade), ';\s+') as x(trade)
) v
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b60e9781c5f5d2052b1db34d12134cb5)

Answer (score 0):

@a_horse_with_no_name

Using your solution I get the following results (I just copy and paste your code into my script):

| instrument_name | date | position | price | tc | .... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USD/EUR | 2021-08-10 10:02:00,+2300,0.84,0.04;2021-08-10 15:53:20,-17000,0.7,0.002 |  |  |  |  |
| USD/CAD | 2021-08-10 12:00:00,+200,1.25,0.02;2021-08-10 16:50:00,+5000,1.1,0.01 |  |  |  |  |
| USD/NOK | 2021-08-10 5:15:00,+1000,1.5,0.015;2021-08-10 9:53:20,-8000,1.4,0.02 |  |  |  |  |

Yesterday night I fixed the issue, but reading your code I just added a couple of things. This is the code:

```
CREATE VIEW trades (instrument_name, trade_dates, trade_position, price_per_unit, transaction_costs)
AS SELECT
        trade_info.instrument_name,
        split_part(unnest(regexp_split_to_array(trade_info.list_of_trade, E';')), ',', 1)::TIMESTAMP AS trade_dates,
        split_part(unnest(regexp_split_to_array(trade_info.list_of_trade, E';')), ',', 2)::INTEGER AS trade_position,
        split_part(unnest(regexp_split_to_array(trade_info.list_of_trade, E';')), ',', 3)::FLOAT8 AS price_per_unit,
        split_part(unnest(regexp_split_to_array(trade_info.list_of_trade, E';')), ',', 4)::FLOAT8 AS transaction_costs
FROM trade_info;
```

The result is this:

| instrument_name | trade_dates | trade_position | price_per_unit | transaction_costs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USD/EUR | 2021-08-10 10:02:00.0 | 2300 | 0.84 | 0.04 |
| USD/EUR | 2021-08-10 15:53:20.0 | -17000 | 0.7 | 0.002 |
| USD/CAD | 2021-08-10 12:00:00.0 | 200 | 1.25 | 0.02 |
| USD/CAD | 2021-08-10 16:50:00.0 | 5000 | 1.1 | 0.01 |
| USD/NOK | 2021-08-10 05:15:00.0 | 1000 | 1.5 | 0.015 |
| USD/NOK | 2021-08-10 09:53:20.0 | -8000 | 1.4 | 0.02 |

@a_horse_with_no_name Thank you for reply, you've been kind :D